# EF Core : error occurs - "The LINQ expression could not be translated after entity id change"

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I changed the entity id from `int` to `guid` and got that problem.

Env: EF Core 5.0.6

Error:

> The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

Code:

```
DbSet<UserProfile>()
    .Where(u => new GeneralUserInfoModel {
        Birthday = u.Birthday,
        CountryInfoId = u.CountryInfoId,
        CountryStateId = u.CountryStateId,
        CustomGender = u.CustomGender,
        FirstName = u.FirstName,
        Gender = u.Gender,
        LanguageSkills = DbSet<LanguageSkills>()
            .Where(l => EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(u, "Id") != null && object.Equals(
                objA: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(u, "Id"),
                objB: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(l, "UserProfileId")))
            .Select(l => new LanguageSkillsModel{
                Id = l.Id,
                LanguageId = l.LanguageId,
                Level = l.Level
            }
            )
            .ToList(),
        LastName = u.LastName,
        OccupationId = u.OccupationId
    }
    .UserId == __id_0)
```

Linq:

```
var result = _unitOfWork.Repository<Domain.Entities.UserProfile>()
                        .Entities
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .Include(x => x.LanguageSkills)
                        .ProjectTo<GeneralUserInfoModel>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserId == request.UserId, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why this `.Where(u => new GeneralUserInfoModel {` ? The `Where` clause is essentially the Where clause in the sql statement and the dotnet clr needs to know how to translate your code into a sql statement at run time. This whole creation of an entity in a Where clause and then comparing the user id does not make sense and wont translate into a sql where clause. That is what the exception is telling you.

Comment: Have you tried to do that without Automapper? Just to remove possible point of failure.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv without automapper same problem. Look like problem with selection itself :O Even simple select doesn't work.

Comment: Problem was with dto. I Forgot to map Id to => UserId :facepalm: